# I Applied for B1/B2 Visa for Business trip, Is it worng ? Should i apply only for B1

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, business-travel

I Applied for B1/B2 Visa for Business trip going to US.

Is it wrong ? Should I apply only for B1 and not for B1/B2?

Comment: You should usually request for only the visa which supports your purpose of visit. Although you will be assigned B1/B2 which would suit both, but you'll have to explain your choice to the officer at the consulate. Make sure that you have all (or more than) the supporting documents. Be courteous - though we invented namaste, their culture is more courteous than ours. My interview was with a very cheerful officer and I wish you the same.

Answer (score 3):

It should be fine.
I've always received a joint B1/B2 anyways when I was asking for just B1 or B2.

Comment: OK but the question was about the opposite situation, so it's not clear that your answer helps. Your experience suggests that they don't see much difference between B1 and B1/B2 but it could, in theory, be that they give a B1/B2 to everybody who asks for B1 or B2, and reject everyone who asks for B1/B2. I'm not proposing that this really happens, but it's a possibility that's not excluded by your evidence.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am not even sure if they issue anything else but a combined B1/B2.

Comment: They issues B1/B2 visa for 10 years. I read that it is done so, in manner to put pressure to visa officials: if they are not sure about issuing a visa, they will not be tempted for a restricted visa limited on time. So they fully trust you or they will not issue a visa.

Comment: The [visa issuance statistics](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-statistics/nonimmigrant-visa-statistics/monthly-nonimmigrant-visa-issuances.html) show that virtually everyone gets a B1/B2 visa, presumably regardless of what they actually chose on their application.